# Unexpected end in PHP script

Tags: php

I really can't find the error. Here is my code:

```
<?
    // Action: add news
    if( array_key_exists('create_new', @$_POST) )
    {
?>
  ...
<?
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Before this my problem was in construction: `<?=...;?>` My web server (Apache) did not understand the syntax so I rewrote the method without it, but now I really can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a space   before the `?` and after the `;` here:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>
```

Replace all `<?` by `<?php`

Comment: Okay, but why? All time before I used <? not <?php. Could I enable this?

Comment: Its in the php.ini search for short_tags or similar.

Comment: I don't see how this can be a short tags issue: the implication of changing <? to <?php is that it's in short tags form and therefore not being parsed by PHP, which is obviously not the case as otherwise the code would just be returned to the browser, as opposed to the error "unexpected $end in php" (which I assume is what the OP is getting, according to the question title).

Answer (score 1):

`@$_POST` should just be `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

you should you the alternate if syntax:

```
<?php
// Action: add news
if( array_key_exists('create_new', @$_POST) ):

?>
...
<?php
  exit();
  endif;
?>
```

it's also better to use the

Answer (score 0):

You're apparently missing a close brace. I hate to say it, but without the complete code, it's pretty hard for us to tell you where the problem is... so either I think we need to see the complete code, or you'll have to sit down with a decent editor and trace the opening and closing braces.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's a bit odd, if you put a semi-colon after a brace in this kind of scenario, it'll get rid of your errors.

```
<?
    // Action: add news
    if( array_key_exists('create_new', @$_POST) )
    {
?>
  ...
<?
        exit();
    };
?>
```

Note the second to last line now has a semi-colon AFTER the brace.